# Appending loop number to SQL row variable

Tags: php, sql, variables

"Undefined variable: payout_item_1" so it's getting the variable name correctly but I must have the format wrong.

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) {
    echo "<input name = 'payout_item_" . $x . "' type = 'text' value = '" . $row[${"payout_item_" . $x}] . "' style = 'width : 150px;' ";
}
```

Comment: please check you have passed payout_item from server side or not..

Comment: What does a `var_dump($row)` show?

Comment: Can you supply more code in your question to help people help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making a couple assumptions

1. You have a table with columns `"payout_item_1"` through `"payout_item_5"`
2. You do not have variables called `$payout_item_1` through `$payout_item_5` in which the actual column names are stored.

Currently your code is building [variable variables](http://$row[$%7B%22payout_item_%22%20.%20$x%7D]):

This statement builds a variable name with payout_item_1 (in the first iteration). Effectively `$payout_item_1`.

```
${"payout_item_" . $x}
```

The code is then looking for a value in that variable to use as the column header name. Effectively, it's expecting somewhere further up for there to be something akin to

```
$payout_item_1 = "column1";
```

Which, as the error suggests, it cannot find. If my assumption in 1. was correct, all you need to do is reformat to

```
$row["payout_item_" . $x]
```

and you will be referencing the column `payout_item_1` (through 5) from your `$row` object. Written literally:

```
$row["payout_item_1"]
```

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. I had tried many variations of that but must have missed the magic combination. Lack of sleep probably didn't help either. Thanks! You rock!